# From within Powershell, how do I pass an IEnumerable argument?

Tags: powershell, lync

I'm trying to use the  Microsoft.Lync.Model.Contact.GetContactInformation() method. There are two versions, one which takes a plain enum, and another which takes an IEnumerable with multiple values.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lync/hh347568.aspx

I can use the first version semi-successfully (until I try to retrieve one for which there is no value), but I can't make any sense of how I'm supposed to pass in the multiple arguments.

```
$contactInfo = $c[$c.Count - 1].Participants[1].Contact.GetContactInformation([int[]]("FirstName", "LastName", "DisplayName", "PrimaryEmailAddress"))
```

(The above doesn't work.)

Can someone nudge me in the right direction?

Comment: Why are you casting the string array to an int array?

Comment: How would I know, I'd rather be writing a bash script. Actually, I'd rather that Microsoft wrote software that was mildly extensible, so I didn't have to wade into this crap just to get a Growl notification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest syntax would be close to what you have now.  The method takes an enumeration of `ContactInformationType` values, so your cast should be to an array of those, not `int`.

Also, you can use `$foobar[-1]` as sugar for `$foo[$foo.Count - 1]`, i.e. to get the last element.

```
$contactInfo = $c[-1].Participants[1].Contact.GetContactInformation([Microsoft.Lync.Model.ContactInformationType[]] @("FirstName", "LastName", "DisplayName", "PrimaryEmailAddress"))
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it will work if you try something like below:

```
$contactInfo = $c[$c.Count - 1].Participants[1].Contact.GetContactInformation(
                [int[]](
                        [int]Microsoft.Lync.Model::ContactInformationType.FirstName,
                        [int]Microsoft.Lync.Model::ContactInformationType.LastName,
                        [int]Microsoft.Lync.Model::ContactInformationType.DisplayName,
                        [int]Microsoft.Lync.Model::ContactInformationType.PrimaryEmailAddress))
```

Answer (score 1):

The method itself probably doesn't know what "FirstName" is. Try creating an array of the enum-values, like:

```
$information = [Microsoft.Lync.Model.ContactInformationType]::FirstName, [Microsoft.Lync.Model.ContactInformationType]::LastName, [Microsoft.Lync.Model.ContactInformationType]::DisplayName, [Microsoft.Lync.Model.ContactInformationType]::PrimaryEmailAddress
$contactInfo = $c[$c.Count - 1].Participants[1].Contact.GetContactInformation($information)
```